# Usages inside #if statement is not being indexed

Tags: c#, rider, preprocessor-directive

I have two classes. There is `#if` statement, that decides which class should be used.

Example:

```cs
public class DebugTool { }
```

```cs
public class ReleaseTool { }
```

```cs
...
#if RELEASE
var tool = new ReleaseTool();
#elseif
var tool = new DebugTool();
#endif
...
```

The problem is that, while I'm working with debug configuration(or any configuration, that doesn't define `RELEASE`), rider shows me that there is no any usages of `ReleaseTool` class. And, if I remove `ReleaseTool`, I would not get any error until I cook a release build.

So is there a way to index all usages from all `#if` statements, including those ones, which will not be compiled with current configuration?

P.S It's just an example. I need exactly what I've asked. Solutions like "Place `ReleaseTool` under `#if RELEASE`" don't suit.

Comment: Consider something like `#if RELEASE const bool isRelease = true;` and then `var tool = isRelease ? new ReleaseTool() : new DebugTool()`, making both implement `ITool` or suchlike. A `static readonly` also suffices. The JIT compiler can eliminate such checks efficiently, so there is no performance penalty.

Comment: does "release" class declaration is under the ifdef RELEASE statement ?

Comment: You could add `var unusedTool = new ReleaseTool();` to the `#else` branch.